# MySQL: Update value of UNIQUE key column without duplicating lines

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to UPDATE a value of a column which is part of three-columns UNIQUE KEY.
When I try to update this value, MySQL doesn't throw any error and duplicates lines instead of updating them.

```
id     | idpage | itemnature | itemindex | label | deleted
-------+--------+------------+-----------+-------+--------
208461 | 30331  |          4 |         1 |       |       0
208491 | 30331  |          4 |        11 |       |       0
208521 | 30331  |          4 |        21 |       |       0
208451 | 30331  |          6 |         1 |       |       0
208481 | 30331  |          6 |        11 |       |       0
208511 | 30331  |          6 |        21 |       |       0
208441 | 30331  |         10 |         1 |       |       0
208471 | 30331  |         10 |        11 |       |       0
208501 | 30331  |         10 |        21 |       |       0
```

[image]

And here's my queries which don't work as expected:

```
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 1 WHERE id = 208471;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 1 WHERE id = 208481;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 1 WHERE id = 208491;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 2 WHERE id = 208441;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 2 WHERE id = 208451;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 2 WHERE id = 208461;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 3 WHERE id = 208501;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 3 WHERE id = 208511;
UPDATE wcms.page_structure SET itemindex = 3 WHERE id = 208521;
```

When I do this, I get more than 9 rows!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the before and after that you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Strawberry. I don't see two rows with the same id.